# install4j: "Require privileges" action behaves differently for installer and uninstaller in silent mode

Tags: install4j

I have:

- *install4j Multi-Platform Edition 6.1.3 (build 6299)*
- Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
- Java 1.8.0_45

When I ran the installer in silent mode in non-root user, the installation succeeded. However, the un-installation required me to be a root user to run.

Here is the configuration for my installer:

[image: Installation configurations for privileges]

Here is the configuration for my uninstaller:

[image]

Here is log snippet for installation showing the "Request privileges" action succeeded.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequestPrivilegesAction [ID 2776]: Execute action
   Property failIfNotRootUnix: false
   Property obtainIfAdminMac: false
   Property obtainIfAdminWin: true
   Property obtainIfNormalMac: false
   Property obtainIfNormalWin: false
   Property failIfNotObtainedWin: true
   Property allRequested: false
   Property failIfNotObtainedMac: true
   Property rollbackSupported: false
   Execute action successful after 2 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.StartupScreen [ID 15]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.WelcomeScreen [ID 1]: Show screen
```

Here is log snippet for un-installation showing the "Require installer privileges" action failed due to insufficient rights.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequireInstallerPrivilegesAction [ID 2779]: Execute action
   Property failIfNotObtained: true
   Property rollbackSupported: false
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RequireInstallerPrivilegesAction [ID 2779]: Execute action not successful after 4494 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.LoadResponseFileAction [ID 2778]: Rollback action
   Rollback action finished
```

Did I mis-configure anything?

**Edit:**
Here is the variables in a varfile that I passed in the command line when I ran the installer & uninstaller:

```
logLocation=/folder/something
storeLocation=/folder/something
storeSize$Long=1
nmx.webserver.port$Long=8466
nmx.sharedDir=/folder/something
nmx.licenceFileName=/folder/something
nmx.userDir=/folder/something
sys.adminRights$Boolean=true
sys.languageId=en
sys.programGroupDisabled$Boolean=true
```

The installer and uninstaller were run consecutively by my test program under a normal user, i.e. the program ran installer and then ran uninstaller.

Comment: Please check if `sys.adminRights` in `.install4j/response.varfile` is set to `true`. In that case, the installer was run with full privileges.

Comment: @IngoKegel Yes, it is set to `sys.adminRights$Boolean=true`. I am confused now because I ran both the installer and uninstaller within my automated tests. If the installer was able to acquire the necessary rights, why could not the uninstaller?

Comment: Maybe try again with a clean installation.

Comment: @IngoKegel what do you mean by `clean installation`? The installer and uninstaller were run in _silent mode_ as part of automated tests. It was installed into a clean folder and the uninstallation was performed on the same folder.

Comment: When the installer runs, the process seems to have full admin rights. Do you have UAC turned off while the installer is running?

Comment: @IngoKegel I did not have UAC turned off. Please see my edits for more details.

Comment: sys.adminRights will be set to true only if the installer detects that the process has full privileges. If I try this on my machine with an admin user and UAC turned on, it will not be set to true. Something must be different in the way you start the processed or the way your machine is configured.